# How to return large list of objects in controller ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, garbage-collection, swagger

We pretend to return a large list of objects in ASP.NET as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProgramConfiguration>>> Find([FromQuery] ProgramConfigurationQuery programConfigurationQuery)
{
            Log.Information("Find all programs");
            ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProgramConfiguration>> result;
            IEnumerable<ProgramConfiguration> programConfiguration;           

            try
            {
                programConfiguration = await programConfigurationService.FindAsync(programConfigurationQuery);
                result = Ok(programConfiguration);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                result = BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
}
```

This returns a list of 1000 object. We test performace and in the line result = Ok(programConfiguration); program lose a lot of performance.

We executed swagger of this app in Firefox and Google Chrome. In the first, it is hanged for a few seconds. Chrome do not crashed, but takes a long time.

We take execution performance trace of firefox and we have this result:
[Swagger performace trace execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXZtA.png)

This result it is repeated in FrontEnd platform.

So, how can we improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving a large number of objects at once might take a lot of time. Instead, you can retrieve them in chunks. This solution is called **pagination**. Here is how you can implement it:

Function definition:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProgramConfiguration>>> Find([FromQuery] ProgramConfigurationQuery programConfigurationQuery, int skip = 0, int take = 20)
```

Data retrieval:

```
programConfiguration = await programConfigurationService.FindAsync(programConfigurationQuery).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```